# Find a diagonal form of the quadratic form $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i^2 + \sum_{i < j}x_ix_j$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Find a diagonal form of the quadratic form
$$f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i^2 + \sum_{i < j}x_ix_j.$$

It turned out to be such a problem:
How to change quadratic form $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i^2 + \sum_{i < j}x_ix_j$ into diagonal form?

We can solve it with congruent transformation, although it is a little complex.
Besides, I tried to transform it into a diagonal form by orthogonal transformation, since its quadratic matrix has the same diagonal elements and the same non-diagonal elements(I thought that I can find a simple way to find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but failed. Maybe you can try it).

Is there any other way?

Comment: What is "standard form"? Is it $f(x) = (Ax \mid x)$ for some simmetric linear transformation $A$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't translate very well. The term may be diagonal form. such as this form $q(x)=a_1 x_1^2 + a_2 x_2^2+ \ldots +a_n x_n^2$

Comment: I see, you want a change of variables to make $f$ diagonal.

Comment: yes, I try to solve the problem with congruent transformation, but it is a little complex. I wonder if there is any other way, such as orthogonal transformation

Comment: By the way, I did not vote down. Some people do but they are not coming to give reasons for their votes. Such a shameful behaviour.

Comment: emmmm, may be the question is too simple or i didn't express well

Comment: I guess the negative attention is due to the formulation not being at par with [our guidelines for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Some of the voters may even think this is an attempt to oursource homework.

Comment: Anyway, please clarify whether you want diagonalization to preserve the metric, IOW whethere you want an orthogonal transformation or not.

Comment: Thanks. I probably understand what you mean.

Comment: A way to get started on problems like this is to get your hands dirty, and do a few small cases. $n=2$ is a case in point. Normalizing the basis $\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$ should give you what you want :-)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, and I will modify the problem description and give my solution when I am free. maybe tomorrow

Comment: For interest, the case of three variables is a special case where you can get the neat form $\frac 12(x+y)^2+\frac 12 (y+z)^2+\frac 12(z+x)^2$ if you change the signs of the cross terms to "-" and also use $(x-y)^2$ etc instead of $(x+y)^2$ you get a form which is occasionally useful in dealing with identified and inequalities in three variables eg $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$ contains a term of this form which is known to be non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $M$ of this quadratic form has the form
$$
M=\frac12(I_n+J_n),
$$
where $J_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with all ones.

The eigenvalues of $J_n$ are obviously $\lambda_1=n$ (multiplicity one) and 
$\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\cdots=\lambda_n=0$ (multiplicity $n-1$). Therefore the eigenvalues of $M$ are $(n+1)/2$ (multiplicity one) and $1/2$ (multiplicity $n-1$). Implying that there exists an orthogonal coordinate transformation $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto (x_1',x_2',\ldots,x_n')$ such that in the primed coordinates the quadratic form takes the form
$$
Q(x_1',x_2',\ldots,x_n')=\frac12\left((n+1)x_1'^2+x_2'^2+x_3'^2+\cdots+x_n'^2\right).
$$
An orthonormal basis corresponding to the primed coordinates can be found by orthonormalizing any basis of the $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace 
$$V=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb{R}^n\mid x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=0\}$$
which is equal to the eigenspace of $J_n$ belonging to the eigenvalue zero. The missing basis vector is the unit vector $\dfrac1{\sqrt n}(1,1,\ldots,1)$ spanning the orthogonal complement of $V$.

---

It is (very likely) possible to describe an orthonormal basis of $V$ with a lot of symmetries. I'm not sure I want to go there, though. I would start with a complex basis consisting of roots of unity of order $n$, and go from there.

Comment: As you said, this quadratic form is positive definite. So, $I_n$ is a diagonal form of it according to Sylvester's law of inertia

Comment: Yeah, @congee. $J_n$ is positive semi-definite, and we add a positive multiple of $I_n$ to it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is too long for the comment box.**

The essence of your exercise is given in the following *example.*

Suppose we have $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + xy + xz + yz.$ We *complete the square* by getting rid of one of the variables, say we pick the first one ($x$ in my notation). So you get,
$$\begin{align*}
f(x, y, z) &= (x^2 + xy + xz) + y^2 + z^2 + yz \\
&= \left( x + \dfrac{y}{2} + \dfrac{z}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{y^2}{4} - \frac{z^2}{4} -\frac{yz}{2} + y^2 + z^2 + yz\\
&=u^2 + \dfrac{3y^2}{4} + \dfrac{yz}{2} + \dfrac{3z^2}{4}
\end{align*},$$
where $u = x + \dfrac{y}{2} + \dfrac{z}{2}.$ Now, we can get rid of the second variable, $y$ in my case, by, again, completing the square
$$\begin{align*}
f(x, y, z) &= u^2 + \left( \dfrac{\sqrt{3}y}{2} + \frac{z}{2\sqrt{3}} \right)^2-\dfrac{z^2}{12}+\dfrac{3z^2}{4} = u^2 + v^2+\dfrac{5}{6}z^2
\end{align*},$$
which is a required representation of $f.$

The case with $x_1, \ldots, x_p$ is just guessing a pattern and using induction (I am guessing).

Comment: I've tried this method to deal directly with situation that has $n$ variables, but it seems hard to handle for me. It seems that it's easy to find the rule from a simple point of view. Thank you.

Comment: @WillM. When you complete the square, you should put $-\frac{yz}2$ instead of $-\frac{yz}4$, because $\left(x+\frac y2+\frac z2\right)^2=x^2+\frac{y^2}4+\frac{z^2}4+xy+xz+\frac{yz}2$. But then, I don't see how you group together a common factor $\frac34$ in the passage that follows.

Comment: (correction: I do see how to deal with it, but the error is still there)

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice it just now.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path this brute force completing the square method always work... provided you can do the arithmetic. I usually cannot.